Estoy programando en mi clase controladora un método que me debe devolver un Array que contenga los trabajadores con más años de experiencia
El problema en mi código es que al ejecutarlo me devuelve siempre el ultimo trabajador directivo; no el o los trabajadored que más años de experiencia tiene/n
public ArrayList<Trabajadores> mayorExperiencia(){
     ArrayList<Trabajadores>trabajadoresEncontrados = null;
   
    for(Trabajadores trab:trabajadores){
        int mayorExp=0;
        if(trab instanceof TrabajadorDirectivo){
             
            if(((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia()>mayorExp){
               trabajadoresEncontrados =new ArrayList<>();
                mayorExp=((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia();
                trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
            }else {
                if(((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia()==mayorExp){
                 trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);   
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    return trabajadoresEncontrados;
 }


Recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron!

El error es que en cada iteración reinicias mayorExp a cero. Esa inicialización hay que hacerla solo una vez
public ArrayList<Trabajadores> mayorExperiencia(){
    ArrayList<Trabajadores>trabajadoresEncontrados = new ArrayList();
   
    int mayorExp=0;
    for(Trabajadores trab:trabajadores){
        if (trab instanceof TrabajadorDirectivo){

            int exp = ((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia()        

            if (exp > mayorExp){
                trabajadoresEncontrados = new ArrayList<>();
                mayorExp = exp
                trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
                }
            else if (exp == mayorExp){
                    trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);   
                    }                
            }
        }
    return trabajadoresEncontrados;
 }

También usa una variable intermedia exp para no calcular dos veces lo mismo y dejar el código más legible.
También es mejor inicializar trabajadoresEncontrados con una lista vacia, para no tener que lidiar con null. Así la función siempre retorna una lista.

Tiene que hacer dos recorridos.. uno para ver cual es el año mayor, y despues de vuelta para ver que trabajadores estan en ese estado... esto ya se lo dije en otra pregunta...

@gbianchi. Cada vez que encuentra un año mayor, descarta todos los anteriores. Cada vez que encuentra una año igual, lo agrega a la lista. Los años menores los descarta. Basta con una pasada diria yo.

ah si es asi esta perfe!

Gracias por su tiempo , problema resuelto

El problema principal se debe a que cada vez que iteras  mayorExp, tiene el valor de 0
for(Trabajadores trab:trabajadores){
        int mayorExp=0;
        ...
        ...
}

Realiza los siguiente scambios
public ArrayList<Trabajadores> mayorExperiencia() {

    ArrayList<Trabajadores> trabajadoresEncontrados = new ArrayList<>();

    int mayorExp = 0;

    for (Trabajadores trab : trabajadores) {
        if (trab instanceof TrabajadorDirectivo) {
            //*Obten experiencia actual en una variable          
            int expActual = ((TrabajadorDirectivo) trab).getAnnosExperiencia();

            if (expActual > mayorExp) {

                trabajadoresEncontrados = new ArrayList<>();
                trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
                mayorExp = expActual;

            } else if (expActual == mayorExp) { //** Trabajador con experiencia maxima y se agregar al arraylist.
                trabajadoresEncontrados.add(trab);
            }
        }
    }

    return trabajadoresEncontrados;

}


Gracias por tu tiempo , problema solucionado

Solución con interfaz comparable
La solución más adpatable que creo que puedes usar es implementar la interfaz Comparable. Puedes adapatarlo a tu criterio, por ejemplo, después de los años de experiencia puedes añadir otro criterio como nivel de estudios, certificaciones obtenidas, etc.
Porteriormente puedes obtenerlas de distintas maneras, puedes usar ciclos for, streams, Collections, etc. Te dejo un ejemplo con 2 iguales
package UHTM;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String ...args) {
        ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Worker("Alan", 5),
            new Worker("Bob", 3),
            new Worker("Sara", 3),
            new Worker("Carl", 2),
            new Worker("Dan", 1),
            new Worker("Alice", 5)
        ));

        int max = workers.stream().max(Worker::compareTo).map(Worker::experience).orElseThrow();
        workers.stream().filter(w -> w.experience == max).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private record Worker(String name, int experience) implements Comparable<Worker> {
    @Override
        public int compareTo(Worker o) {
            if (Objects.equals(null, o))
                return -1;
            return Integer.compare(this.experience, o.experience);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " has " + experience + " years of experience";
        }
    }
}

Por ejemplo, se puede implementar ahora con fechas
public static void main(String ...args) {
        ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                new Worker("Alan", LocalDate.of(1998, Month.APRIL, 1)),
                new Worker("Bob", LocalDate.of(2004, Month.MARCH, 15)),
                new Worker("Sara", LocalDate.of(2012, Month.JANUARY, 10)),
                new Worker("Carl", LocalDate.of(2021, Month.NOVEMBER, 20)),
                new Worker("Dan", LocalDate.of(2022, Month.MAY, 5)),
                new Worker("Alice", LocalDate.of(1998, Month.APRIL, 1))
        ));

        LocalDate max = workers.stream().max(Worker::compareTo).map(Worker::experience).orElseThrow();
        workers.stream().filter(w -> w.experience.equals(max)).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private record Worker(String name, LocalDate experience) implements Comparable<Worker> {
    @Override
        public int compareTo(Worker o) {
            if (Objects.equals(null, o))
                return -1;
            return -this.experience.compareTo(o.experience);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + " has " + ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(experience, LocalDate.now()) + " years of experience";
        }
    }

